# Octopus Deployment to Production environment

Tags: octopus-deploy, octopus

Using Octopus I want to be able to have a set up so that attempting to deploy to a Production environment includes a warning to the user and a manual intervention to continue, to prevent accidental Production deployments.

I don't want this to happen on other environments e.g.

Development > Staging > UAT > Production (only show the warning deploying UAT to Production).

I've been unable to find if there is a way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure steps to only run in specific environments.

[image: Deployment step conditions section]

Comment: Can you add more detail, such as the use of tenants, tenant tags, or different projects targeting different environments?